# Properties of Exponentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am a Computer Programmer and this Question might be too trivial to true practitioners of pure Mathematics.

I recently came across a programming puzzle (**Project Euler #29**). I have to find out the distinct numbers formed by the expression **a<sup>b</sup>** when `2 ≤ a ≤ 100 and 2 ≤ b ≤ 100`.

I know that the maximum possible is less than `99 X 99 = 9801`.

So I tried to count the Numbers which are equal, for example 2<sup>4</sup> = 4<sup>2</sup> and subtract this count from 9801.

So my question is under what circumstances **a<sup>b</sup> = c<sup>d</sup>** ? Provided `a ≠ c` and `b ≠ d`.

I used the following check, `c MOD a = 0` and `b MOD d = 0`. But I got incorrect results.

Then I checked if  **c = a<sup>m</sup>** and **b = d<sup>n</sup>**, for `m ≥ 1` and `n ≥ 1`. This again proved an insufficient check as numbers like 2<sup>4</sup> and 4<sup>4</sup> where found equal.

More over I can not find the actual values of  a<sup>b</sup> as it requires calculating numbers as large as 100<sup>100</sup> (Not in a Mathematical way, I mean Programming wise because no data type might be large enough to hold such results). So what I require is to check whether **a<sup>b</sup> = c<sup>d</sup>** without calculating either **a<sup>b</sup>** or **c<sup>d</sup>**. Is it possible? If possible what are the checking criteria?

If there are some problems with the question format please post a comment I will update the Question.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you factor out $a^b$ into prime powers $p_1^{k1}p_2^{k2}...p_n^{kn}$ this would mean that b devides all $k_i$.
So for every divisor $d$ such that $d$ devides all $k_i$
$$c = p_1^{\frac{k1}{t}}p_2^{\frac{k2}{t}}...p_n^{\frac{kn}{t}} \in \mathbb{Z}$$
To this algorithmically you shold compute factor out $a^b$ find the GCD(k1,k2,...,kn)(greatest common devisor) = G. Then for every possible devisor of G there exist such numbers. You might want to look at algorithms how to find the GCD and the number of possible devisors of a number.

Comment: +1 and Thanks. But the problem is that I don't have the value of a^b and c^d. All I have is the values of a, b, c and d. Then is it possible to check whether a^b = c^d?

Comment: Well basically factor out a^b in the following way - Store a as a datastructure array of the form A={0,0,1,3,0,2,...} where b[i] = $k_i$ in my notation, but here $p_i$ is the i-th prime number (so $p_0$ is 2, $p_1$ is 3 and so on), thats why u can have zeros. Now after you have a like that then $a^b$ is just the whole array A mutliplied by b. In the same manner you can get and c^d or use what is upwards and find all possible c and d, it's up to you.

Comment: Thank You. I think I can work it out.